# fetch sends [object Object] instead of File object

Tags: react-native

I'm using [Expo](http://expo.io/) and its [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker) to grab the image from gallery. It returns both `uri` and `base64`.

Now I want to upload the image in a `multipart/form-data` request.

The problem is that the server only accepts `File` while below code sends `[object Object]` instead.

[Image of the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfQbN.png)

```
const formData = new FormData();

const data = {
  jwt,
};

formData.append('message', JSON.stringify(data));

formData.append('avatar', {
  uri: avatar,
  type: 'image/png',
  name: 'avatar.png'
});

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
})
```

Since I'm using Expo I'm limitted to libraries that it supports. Also adding `Content-Type` header doesn't work at all and server can't even recognize the message.

Comment: same issue for me . not able to resolve this issue. Does anyone have done this?

Comment: same issue here, did you find a solution ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but on React Native CLI. The file is the actual file object up until I append it to the FormDate, at which point it becomes the string `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

If you see that file being sent as `[object object]` in your request params, that might occur due to two reasons:

1. The file that you are sending **is not** a file (or not a file object).
   A FormData should only receive a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object in order to be sent on a request.
   Note that you have the right keys on your object and that it is indeed a File or a Blob.
2. As mentioned, it might be the `Content-Type` header which should not be set

Comment: In the OP's case, is probable that the URI (`avatar` in `uri: avatar`) is a data URI. In that case, it'd be required to [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata).

Answer (score 0):

For React, if you want to upload image and avoid [object object] error, there is a need to setFile for input type handleChange

```
const file = event.target.files[0]    
setFile({
    picturePreview: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    pictureAsFile: event.target.files[0]
})
```

And then calling in formData like:

```
formData.append('file_attachment', file.pictureAsFile)
```

Full working example here: https://youtu.be/yTGXNvHQ4BQ